Error unmounting filesystem : target is busy
When I format my pendrive, it shows 
Error unmounting filesystem 
Error unmounting /dev/sdb1: target is busy (udisks-error-quark, 14)
I need to format it, any solution here?

You probably have a process running that has it mounted. This might be 'files/nautilus' and you have clicked on the temporary 'usb' file system which will mount it. I believe that even if you close the process it will remain mounted.  From the open process right click on it and select unmount.
